# 'catch branch identical to filenotfoundexception branch' doesnt let me to catch

Tags: android, exception

I got an error to `catch (FileNotFoundException e)` when I also catch `catch (IOException e)`.

it is telling me to collapse catch blocks and when i click ro collapse it deleting the `catch (FileNotFoundException e)` and the error move to the `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);` line.

what to do?

this part of code:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream;

            try {
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                Log.d("d", "created image");
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Logcat error:

08-09 14:50:58.053 4832-4832/com.example.smite.floater D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM 08-09 14:50:58.053 4832-4832/com.example.smite.floater W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d0cb20) 08-09 14:50:58.057 4832-4832/com.example.smite.floater E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.smite.floater, PID: 483 java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.smite.floater.DialogEditText$1.onClick(DialogEditText.java:79)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the exact error's text?

Comment: `08-09 14:50:58.053    4832-4832/com.example.smite.floater D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-09 14:50:58.053    4832-4832/com.example.smite.floater W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d0cb20)
08-09 14:50:58.057    4832-4832/com.example.smite.floater E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.smite.floater, PID: 4832
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.smite.floater.DialogEditText$1.onClick(DialogEditText.java:79)`

Answer (score 1):

Try removing FileNotFoundException block from your code.

```
//catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               // e.printStackTrace();
 // }
```

FileNotFoundException is subclass of IOException.